# Will @PersistenceUnit close my EntityManagerFactory when application is destroyed?

Tags: java, annotations, entitymanager, persistence-unit

If i use the following

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="mongo")
EntityManagerFactory emf;

EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Will this annotation make sure that the EntityManagerFactory closes gracefully when application is destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes an injected EntityManagerFactory is automatically closed by the container.